# Can uglifyjs ignore undefined symbols

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

The first file that I am passing to uglifyjs declares some namespaces like

```
window.MyNamespace = {}
```

when uglifyjs sees this line it complains that window is not defined.

Is there a way to have uglifyjs ignore undefined symbols? I have tried using the --no-dead-code option

Comment: What version of uglify are you using and how did you get it? I don't see this when I uglify the same text.

Comment: I am using 1.2.5. Do you have any other options set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your global code in a function:

```
(function(window) {
  window.whatever = something;
  // ...
})(this);
```

You  can also do this:

```
(function(window) {
  "use strict";

  // ...

})(this);
```

which is probably a good idea anyway.  You'll get warnings/errors from stray undefined variables even without uglify.